# Can any one help me desipher this error that I am getting while trying to open a port with a dll

Tags: delphi, dll, tcp

Can any one help me desipher this error that I am getting while trying to open a port with a dll.  I am getting an erro: "Access violation at address 0003D078" When I call SAAT_Open(myCharPtrOpen). Not sure if I am defininig the Handle correctly on unit UntRFIDAPI.  Is the variable PHandle define correctly?
Here is my code:

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var
   myString, myString2  : string;
   myCharPtrInit: PChar;
   myCharPtrOpen: PChar;
   i : Integer;
   Open, Init: Boolean;
 begin
  // Create a string of Char's
  myString  := '&hp';
  // Point to the first character in the string
  i := 1;
  myCharPtrInit := Addr(myString[i]);
  if SAAT_TCPInit(myCharPtrInit,'192.168.3.238',7086) = True then
  begin
    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Initiated'; //ShowMessage('Initiated');
    myString2 := 'hp';
    myCharPtrOpen := Addr(myString2[i]);
    if SAAT_Open(myCharPtrOpen) = True then StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Opened';   
  end;
end;


unit UntRFIDAPI;

INTERFACE
uses
  SysUtils, Windows, Messages, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Dialogs,
  StdCtrls, Forms, DBCtrls, DB, Grids, DBGrids,Mask, ExtCtrls,
  Buttons, WinTypes;

var
  A: String;

function SAAT_TCPInit(pHandle: Pointer; pHostName: String; nsocketPort: Integer):Boolean; stdcall;
function SAAT_Open(pHandle: Pointer):Boolean; stdcall;
function SAAT_Close(pHandle: Pointer):Boolean; stdcall;

implementation

function SAAT_TCPInit;  external 'RFIDAPI.dll';
function SAAT_Open;  external 'RFIDAPI.dll';
function SAAT_Close;  external 'RFIDAPI.dll';

end.
```

Here is the API call:

1.1 Initialize Ethernet Port(TCP) connection

```
//TCP parameters initialization 
//Functionality：import by parameter, initialize TCP to prepare for opening connection
//Parameters： 
//  pHandle for preserving the opening ports handl 
//  pHostName reader IP address, only effective under the ethernet communication 
//  nsocketPort network SOCKET port 
//Returned value：true: Operation Succeeded, false Operation Failed 

bool SAAT_TCPInit (void** pHandle,char *pHostName,int nsocketPort)
```

If the IP connecting to the reader is 192.168.0.238, port is 7086, then calling as follows:

```
HANDLE hp; 
if (!SAAT_TCPInit(&hp, ”192.168.0.238”, 7086)) 
{ 
    printf("reader initialization failed!\n"); 
    return false; 
}
```

Comment: Your imports are wrong. string is not valid for interop. Show the C++ declarations for these functions. And everything else looks wrong too.

Comment: How should I define my imports?

Comment: You'll have to work that out for yourself unless you show the other side of the interop. We've got no idea how these functions are defined in the C++ header file, or how they are to be called. Perhaps that's what the final paragraph attempts to do, but it is unreadable. If you can make it readable, I'm sure I can show the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your time.  Here is what they want me to do:

Comment: No. Please edit the question to make it readable. Once it is formatted it's really easy to translate. I just cannot read it now. I could do it for you, but then you would not learn.

Comment: //TCP parameters initialization 
//Functionality：import by parameter, initialize TCP to prepare for opening connection 
//Parameters： 
// pHandle for preserving the opening ports handl 
// pHostName reader IP address, only effective under the ethernet communication 
// nsocketPort network SOCKET port 
//Returned value：true: Operation Succeeded, false Operation Failed bool SAAT_TCPInit (void** pHandle,char *pHostName,int nsocketPort)

Comment: Also unreadable. Maybe somebody else will help. I won't until you edit the question. Please let me teach you how to ask a question.

Comment: Ok, Please do! I am new to dll calling from Delphi.

Comment: What part of my comments above do you not understand? How could I have been any clearer? Do you know how to edit a question?

Comment: Do you want me to change my question ?

Comment: Well, @Rudy fixed the question already

Comment: @user734781: the formatting of that last part was terrible. I made it a little more readable. This helps people understand the entire question better, and to see what actually the problem could be.

Comment: @Rudy The asker still has not learnt to edit questions. That was what I was hoping to teach the asker. Obviously it's up to you how you edit questions but I was really hoping that the asker could learn something. That has not happened. The asker can take away the thought that there is no need to make any effort in asking the question because somebody else will do that. That's all.

Comment: I don't know the asker, but a good example can sometimes help, IMO. I also did it to understand the question myself.

Comment: @Rudy I'm sad because I don't think asker has learnt anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Rudy and David pointed out, your translation of the `SAAT_TCPInit()` function signature is wrong, and your use of a pointer handle with this API is wrong.  They already explained why your code is wrong, so I won't repeat the reasons.  They have some minor issues with their answers, though.

Your Delphi code should look more like this instead:

```
unit UntRFIDAPI;

interface

function SAAT_TCPInit(out pHandle: Pointer; pHostName: PAnsiChar; nsocketPort: Integer): Boolean; stdcall;
function SAAT_Open(pHandle: Pointer): Boolean; stdcall;
function SAAT_Close(pHandle: Pointer): Boolean; stdcall;

implementation

const
  RFIDAPIDLL = 'RFIDAPI.dll';

function SAAT_TCPInit; external RFIDAPIDLL;
function SAAT_Open; external RFIDAPIDLL;
function SAAT_Close; external RFIDAPIDLL;

end.
```

```
procedure TForm5.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  hp: Pointer;
begin
  if SAAT_TCPInit(hp, '192.168.3.238', 7086) then
  begin
    StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Initiated';
    if SAAT_Open(hp) then
      StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Opened';   
    ...
    SAAT_Close(hp);
  end;
end;
```

For reference, here is the content of the DLL's [`RFIDAPIEXPORT.h`](ftp://support.danbit.dk/drivers/R/RFID865-8/SAAT-800-EUROPE-ENGLISH/API%20Interface%20Development%20Kit/DLL/RFIDAPIEXPORT.h) header file for C++:

```cpp
/***********************************************************************
* Module:  RFIDEXPORT.h
* Author:  
* Modified: 
* Purpose: 
***********************************************************************/
#pragma once

#ifndef  _RFIDEXPORT_H
#define  _RFIDEXPORT_H

#ifdef RFIDAPI_EXPORTS
#define RFID_API __declspec( dllexport )
#else
#define RFID_API __declspec( dllimport )
#endif


extern "C"
{
    bool RFID_API __stdcall SAAT_TCPInit(void** pHandle,char *pHostName,int nsocketPort);

    bool RFID_API __stdcall SAAT_COMInit(void** pHandle,unsigned char nBusAddr,char *pComNum,int nBaud );

    bool RFID_API __stdcall SAAT_USBInit(void** pHandle,unsigned char nBusAddr,char * pUSBNum,int nBaud );

    bool RFID_API __stdcall SAAT_UDPInit(void** pHandle,char *pHostName,int nsocketPort);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_Open(void* pHandle);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_Close(void *pHandle);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_Reconnect(void *pHandle);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_HeartSend (void* pHandle);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_SysInfSet (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType,unsigned char* pParm,int nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_SysInfQuery (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char *pPara, unsigned char *pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_WorkModeSet (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_ParmOp (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char nStartAddrr, unsigned char nLen,  unsigned char *pData, unsigned char *pDataLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_RFParaSet (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char nParaLen,unsigned char* pPara);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_RFParaQuery (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType,unsigned char* pPara, unsigned char *pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_CommunicatParaSet (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char* pPara, unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_CommunicatParaQuery (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char* pPara,unsigned char *pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_NetParaSet (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char* pPara, unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_NetParaQuery (void* pHandle ,int nType, unsigned char* pPara,unsigned char *pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_TagOpParaSet(void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char *pPara,unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_TagOpParaQuery (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char* pPara, unsigned char *pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_ExtendBroadParaSet (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char pSendChunnel);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_ExtendBroadParaQuery (void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, char* pPara, unsigned char* pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_TotalAntennaParmQuery (void* pHandle,unsigned char *szAntennaPara,unsigned char *pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_AntennaParmQuery (void* pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char * pAntennaEnable,unsigned char *pAntennaPower,unsigned char *pAntennaQueryTime );

    bool  RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_AntennaParmSet(void* pHandle ,unsigned char *pPara,unsigned char nLen );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_SetAntennaPortEnable (void* pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nEnable );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_SetAntennaPower (void* pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nPower );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_SetAntennaTime (void* pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nTime );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_PowerOff(void *pHandle);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_CarrierWaveOp(void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType, unsigned char  nPort);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_IOOperate(void* pHandle,unsigned char nPort,unsigned char nState);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_IOStateQuery(void* pHandle,unsigned char *pState);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_Reboot (void* pHandle,unsigned char nMode);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_Reading_IOConfig (void* pHandle,unsigned char nConfigBit);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_Reading_IOQuery (void* pHandle,unsigned char* pConfigBit);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_IOPulseWidthSet (void* pHandle,unsigned char nIOPort,unsigned char nWidth);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_IOPulseWidthQuery (void* pHandle,unsigned char nIOPort,unsigned char* pWidth);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall  SAAT_6BTagSelect ( void* pHandle, unsigned char nType, unsigned char nStartAddr,
                                            unsigned char nDataBite, unsigned char * Data );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall  SAAT_6BReadUIDCode (void *pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nType);

    int  RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6BRevUIDMsg (void *pHandle, unsigned char* nAntenna, unsigned char* pUIDData,
        unsigned char* nUIDLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6BReadUserData ( void *pHandle ,unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nType,unsigned char * pTagID,unsigned char nStartAddr,unsigned char nReadLen, unsigned char *pdata,unsigned char dataLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6BWriteUserData (void* pHandle,
        unsigned char nAntenna,
        unsigned char nType, 
        unsigned char *pTagID,
        unsigned char nStartAddr,
        unsigned char *pValue, 
        unsigned char *pLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6BTagLock (void* pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char nType,
        unsigned char *pTagID, unsigned char nStartAddrr,  unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6BTagLockQuery (void* pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna, 
        unsigned char *pTagID, unsigned char nStartAddr,  unsigned char nLen,unsigned char *pData,unsigned char nDataLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CTagSelect (  void *pHandle, unsigned char nBank ,unsigned short nStartAddr,unsigned char MaskBit, 
        unsigned char *Data ,unsigned char Datalength,unsigned char nSessionZone,
        unsigned char nActiveFlag, unsigned char nCutFlag );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CReadEPCCode ( void *pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char nType,
        unsigned int nTagCount);

    int  RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CRevEPCMsg (void *pHandle, unsigned char* nAntenna, unsigned char* pEPCData,
        unsigned char* nEPCLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall  SAAT_6CReadTIDCode ( void *pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char nType, unsigned int nTagCount);

    int  RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CRevTIDMsg (void *pHandle, unsigned char* nAntenna, unsigned char* pTIDData, unsigned char* nTIDLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall  SAAT_6CWriteEPCCode ( void* pHandle,unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nType,
        unsigned char *pAccessPWD, unsigned char *pWriteData,unsigned char nLen );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CReadUserData ( void* pHandle, 
        unsigned char nAntenna, 
        unsigned int StartAddr,
        unsigned int nToReadLen,
        unsigned int nWaitTime,
        unsigned char * UserData,
        unsigned int* pDataLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CWriteUserData (void* pHandle,  
        unsigned char nAntenna, 
        unsigned char nType,  
        unsigned char *pAccessPWD,
        unsigned int  nStartAddr,
        unsigned int nWaitTime,
        unsigned char *pWriteData, 
        unsigned int *pToWriteLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CWriteBankData (void* pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char nType, unsigned char *pAccessPWD,
        unsigned char nBank,  unsigned char *pWriteData, unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CClearBankData (void* pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char nType, unsigned char *pAccessPWD,
        unsigned char nBank, unsigned char nStartAddr, unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CAccessPWDSet (void *pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char nType, unsigned char *pOrgPWD, 
        unsigned char *pNewPWD);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CDestroyPWDSet (void *pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nType, unsigned char *pAccessPWD, 
        unsigned char *pDestroyPWD );

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall  SAAT_6CTagLock (void *pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char *pAccessPWD, unsigned char nType,
        unsigned char nBank);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CTagKill (void *pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char *pDestroyPWD,
        unsigned char *pEPC, int nEPCLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CEASFlagSet (void *pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char nType,
        unsigned char* pAccessPwd,  int nEASFlag);

    bool  RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_6CEASMonitorEnable (void *pHandle, unsigned char nAntenna,unsigned char nSetEAS);

    bool RFID_API __stdcall SAAT_Copyright(void** pHandle, char* copyright);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_SetLanguageType (void* pHandle,char* szType);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_GetErrorMessage(void *pHandle,char *szMsg, int nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_GetErrorCode(void *pHandle,int *pCode);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_SysTest(void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType,unsigned char nAntenna, unsigned char *pTestParm, unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_RawSendData(void* pHandle , unsigned char *pSendData, unsigned char nLen);

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_RawRevData(void* pHandle , unsigned char *pRecvData, unsigned char* pLen,int nWaitTime); 

    bool RFID_API  __stdcall SAAT_RawSendAndRevData(void* pHandle , 
        unsigned char *pSendData,
        unsigned char nLen,
        unsigned char *pRecvData,
        unsigned char *pLen,
        unsigned char nWaitTime); 

    bool RFID_API __stdcall SAAT_EnterTrans(void* pHandle ,unsigned char nType);

    bool RFID_API __stdcall SAAT_ResetWifiBaund(void* pHandle);
};
#endif
```

And here is a link to the DLL's documentation:

[API Calling Quick Start
SAAT-800 Series Reader](ftp://support.danbit.dk/drivers/R/RFID865-8/SAAT-800-EUROPE-ENGLISH/API%20Interface%20Development%20Kit/API%20Calling%20Quickstart%20for%20800%20Series%20Reader.pdf).

Comment: I have no idea why you just did that. You repeated what had already been said and did not bother to explain anything. I find this depressing. Prose has enormous value.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I seem to be the only person who actually bothered to spend a moment to look up the actual C definition of the functions in question. They *are* using `stdcall`. Both you and Rudy mentioned that possibility but did not show what it would look like. Also, Rudy's use of `THandle` is wrong, as you pointed out. So I posted my own answer showing the necessary corrections.

Comment: Why didn't you say so instead of just posting code with no explanation. If you don't explain yourself we'll just have to keep answering the same questions forever? You can write well. I've seen you do it. Your comments, like here, are often very informative. Why not do that in the answers. As for stdcall vs cdecl, it's reasonable for us to work with the info in the question. It's cool that you dug out the header but very poor that it took my comment to make you mention it. I really wish you could write more prose. It would be hugely valuable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I use both mobile devices and PCs to post on StackOverflow. You know how hard it is to write lengthy explanations and code snippets using a mobile keyboard? More often than not, I post something with a mobile device first and then go back later to flesh it out using a PC. Stop judging me when you don't know the reasoning behind how I do things. I'm getting sick of it.

Comment: I wrote my answer on my phone. Your input device is your problem. I stand by what I said. Your answers are far better when you explain why.

Comment: I did't mean to cause any issues, Remy Lebeau, you are too kind.  I have never had any experience with C, so this is all new to me. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: @user734781: Not your fault. I don't have a problem with you. I have a problem with David, but I do not have any means of venting at him privately. It doesn't belong here, sorry. I'm ending this here.

Comment: There's no need for venting. You improved your answer after I criticised it. It still lacks explanation but you do at least point at the other answers for that. Which is just fine. The net result of this is that your answer is better than it was to begin with. Well done. That is a happy ending.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: my use of THandle is not wrong, IMO. Note that in Windows, a handle is typedef'ed as `typedef PVOID HANDLE`. In Delphi, such a handle is translated as `THandle`, which is a `NativeInt`. It is customary to translate handles as `THandle`, so they are not derefenced but simply treated as opaque "magic numbers". And sometimes, a (low) numeric value is returned instead of a valid handle. That is much easier to check with `THandle` than with a plain pointer. I always translate such values as `THandle`, for the reasons given. It is not verbatim, but it is IMO the best way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

```
bool SAAT_TCPInit(void** pHandle,char *pHostName,int nsocketPort)
```

This function yields a new handle which is of type `void*`. In Delphi that maps to `Pointer`, an untyped pointer. Because C only supports pass by value, in order to have the function pass a value out to the caller, the parameter is declared as a pointer to `void*`, that is `void**`.

The `char*` is an input parameter, a pointer to null terminated array of 8 bit characters. That maps to `PAnsiChar`. You absolutely must not use `string` for interop. It's a private Delphi type that is simply not valid for interop.

Since no calling convention is specified, we assume it to be `cdecl`.

The correct translation therefore is:

```
function SAAT_TCPInit(out Handle: Pointer; HostName: PAnsiChar; 
  SocketPort: Integer): Boolean; cdecl; external 'RFIDAPI.dll';
```

We've mapped the handle type, `void*` to `Pointer`. And the use of `out` introduces the extra level of indirection that is needed.

Call it like this:

```
var
  Handle: Pointer;
....
if SAAT_TCPInit(Handle, '192.168.3.238', 7086) then
  ....
```

It is plausible that the functions in the DLL are actually `stdcall`, even though the C prototypes that you present do not specify that. If that is so, and only you can work that out, then you can change the calling convention accordingly. And in fact Remy has dug out the header file and shown that the functions are `stdcall`.

We cannot see the C declarations of the other function, but they look pretty simple. They both seem to accept the handle that was returned by the call to `SAAT_TCPInit`. So they should accept a parameter of type `Pointer`, passed by value. Presumably like this:

```
function SAAT_Open(Handle: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl; external 'RFIDAPI.dll';
```

And similarly for `SAAT_Close`.

In the interests of clarity it would probably be better to define a new type for this handle. Like so:

```
type
  TSAATHandle = type Pointer;
```

Or if you'd rather:

```
type
  TSAATHandle = type NativeUInt;
```

And obviously you'd then use this type rather than `Pointer`.

Comment: I think you could usefully learn how to use this site better. You really need to learn how to 1. Edit questions, 2. Accept answers, 3. Vote. The first item on this list is the most important. That will help you get better help.

Comment: Thank you David.
Not getting any errrors when initializing the port, I get an error while trying to open the port. Here is the function function SAAT_Open(out Handle: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl; external 'RFIDAPI.dll'; Here is how I call it: var Handle2, Handle: Pointer; begin if SAAT_TCPInit(Handle, '192.168.3.238', 7086) then begin StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Initiated'; if SAAT_Open(Handle2) = True then StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Opened'; //ShowMessage('Open');} end;

Comment: Ask Rudy rather than me. You accepted his answer. Even if it erroneously used THandle. I give up. I don't think I can help you. I've tried way beyond the call of duty and you've not listened to a word I said.

Comment: It's almost as if you didn't read my answer. You could find the answer to your latest problem there if you'd read it.

Comment: @David: `THandle` was not *erroneously* chosen. It is not a verbatim translation, but in Delphi, it is the type preferred for such translations. In C, handles are generally pointers and in Delphi, they are generally translated as (opaque) `THandle`. The advantage is that people will not try to derefence them, but simply treat them as "magic numbers". And sometimes, in error conditions, handles with a numeric error value are returned. It is much easier to treat these as NativeInts.

Comment: @Rudy No, you are wrong. THandle is the Win32 type HANDLE.

Comment: @David: yes, and `HANDLE` is defined as `typedef PVOID HANDLE`. Using `THandle` instead of a plain `Pointer` helps avoid several problems, IMO. The verbatim translation is not always the best. Borland did not make `THandle` an integral type for nothing, even if the original has always been a pointer, in C.

Comment: @Rudy THandle is HANDLE. Don't use it for anything else. Here there is an argument to create a new type for this type of handle. For instance `TSAATHandle = type Pointer`. Borland got it wrong when they mapped HANDLE to Integer. That didn't work out when they went to 64 bit. It was easy to see that coming but they got it all wrong. Using THandle here is just wrong. You won't change my mind.

Comment: @Rudy How does NativeInt help? You can format an address as a number easily?

Comment: I don't quite understand. `NativeInt` is a pointer-sized int.

Comment: I will leave it after this, but IMO, `THandle` is the better choice than a plain pointer, or your `TSAATHandle`, declared as a pointer type. Borland got it right, IMO. Since the SAAT people mean the pointer to be a handle, I think `THandle` is exactly right.

Comment: @Rudy THandle is Win32 HANDLE

Comment: Ok, one more: @David: yes, you already said so (although it is also Win64). And it is defined as `typedef PVOID HANDLE`, IOW, as Pointer, in Windows, but as NativeInt in Delphi, for the reasons I gave.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Win64 is just Win32 with bigger pointers. Win16 was a different API. That's the terminology that I use.

Comment: @David. Now you lost me completely, but let's agree we disagree. You prefer a verbatim translation or the declarion of a pointer type, I think translating a handle as a pointer-sized opaque magic number is better.

Comment: I don't really mind Pointer or NativeUInt. Either way is fine. Better to use a new type. THandle is no good at all. 64 bit Windows on AMD64 has the exact same API as 32 bit Windows on x86. Whereas Win16 and Win32 were very different, there is no difference other than pointer size between 32 and 64 bit Windows. So, 64 bit Windows is still Win32 in my eyes. Exact same API.

Answer (score 0):

Your translation of the C headers is pretty much off. I don't have the prototypes for the other functions, but `SAAT_TCPInit` should be declared as:

```
function SAAT_TCPInit(var pHandle: THandle; pHostName: PAnsiChar; nSocketPort: Integer): ByteBool;
    cdecl;
```

C doesn't know anything about Delphi strings, so don't translate C strings as Delphi's type `string`, since it is simply not binary compatible. `char *` should be translated as `PAnsiChar`. `void** pHandle` should be translated as `var pHandle: THandle`. And the calling convention is probably `cdecl`.

This assumes that the normal caling convention is used. If it is set to produce `stdcall`, then you'll have to declare that instead of `cdecl`.

I assume that is the main problem you have. Correct the translation and try again.

For more information about translating C headers, see my article [Pitfalls of converting](http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-convert.html) (Get it now, because the website may be offline for a while, I will be switching the provider).

Comment: Not getting any errrors when initializing the port, I get an error while trying to open the port.  
Here is the function
function SAAT_Open(out Handle: Pointer): Boolean; cdecl; external 'RFIDAPI.dll';
Here is how I call it:
var
  Handle2, Handle: Pointer;

begin
  if SAAT_TCPInit(Handle, '192.168.3.238', 7086) then
  begin
   StatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Initiated';
     if SAAT_Open(Handle2) = True then StatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := 'Opened'; //ShowMessage('Open');}
  end;

Comment: If its not THandle then what is the type?

Comment: It is just a raw `Pointer`, it has no type.

Comment: Is there a chance that you could help code this function correctly ?

Comment: @user Is there any point in us helping if you won't read what we write? Do you want to learn anything or do you just want us to write code which you can paste directly? Wouldn't you like to learn **how** this works, and to **understand**. Then you could do this yourself. I'm frustrated that you don't seem to want to learn. That's what this site is all about.

Comment: FWIW, THandle is appropriate. It is defined as a pointer, in C, and as a NativeInt in Delphi. It is simply an opaque, pointer-sized type.

Comment: The use of `out` is wrong. It is a plain pointer (or THandle, doesn't matter).

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Not trying to start a discussion about fundamentals, but is this site really to learn, or just to ask questions and get answers? It is nice if people learn, but do they have to? Sure, I am more inclined to help if people actually show interest in the matter, but do they have to?

Comment: @Rudy THandle is the Win32 type HANDLE

Comment: @Rudy I get a lot of satisfaction out of helping people. But I don't think it helps them when they can copy/paste code that works, yet not understand why. That's what I felt was poor about Remy's answer here, and to be honest I find that Remy all too often answers in that way. This asker has asked many times and never accepted, until now. This asker post unreadable code in question and comment. I tried to teach them how to do it right. But you did it for them. You learn by doing. I doubt asker has learnt anything much. (cntd.)

Comment: Does asker know how to edit questions and why that is better than comments? Does asker know not to post lots of code in comments? I doubt it? Does asker know why Remy's code works? Again I doubt it. Does asker know how to find the header file and read it? I doubt it? Does asker even know that's where to look? Again I doubt it. I think if we'd handled this differently then asker could have learnt all of these things. Of course it does rely on a willing asker and that may have been missing too.

Comment: I don't know if asker knows all these things or wants to learn them. But AFAIK, this is a place to answer programming questions, not a place to make better people or better programmers out of the askers. If a question is unacceptable, it should be voted down or closed. If you find it unacceptable, ignore it. If asker does not do what is proposed, that's his problem. Note that many others read this, and they can learn from the questions and answers. But it is undoable to try to teach someone who does not want to be taught. And I don't think this is the right place for it either.

Comment: I don't agree. I don't see any point in not trying to teach.  User was engaging. See this comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26819899/can-any-one-help-me-desipher-this-error-that-i-am-getting-while-trying-to-open-a#comment42210548_26819899 but the asker never got the opportunity.